# can not access swagger ui from another pc in the same domain

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

The title is self-explanatory, I can access the swagger UI from the server which I installed it, but could not access it when I'm requesting the URL from another pc in the same network (domain ). I am not using localhost, I tested it with the server name and the IP with no success. The firewall on the server is off but to be sure I added required rules to allow the swagger port to be accessed without interference.

Answer (score 2):

Add context path in your application.properties.

```
server.servlet.context-path=/rootpath
```

And try to access swagger with this context.

```
http://<ip>:8080/rootpath/swagger-ui.html
```

Comment: Hi Abhiijt, thanks for the reply. it didn't work, solved the problem by exporting the project to war file rather than an executable jar and deployed it in Apache Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

try this in .net core:

> builder.WebHost.UseUrls("https://your-api-address:51947",
> "http://your-api-address:5000");